# Injective compact linear operator from infinite dimensional normed space

Tags: normed-spaces, compact-operators

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional normed space. How can I show that there exist a normed space $W$ and an injective compact linear operator $T$ from $V$ to $W$?

Comment: Since the range of a compact operator is always separable,  you'll get in trouble if $V$ is too big.  Is it OK to assume $V$ is separable?

Comment: @Ruy I am considering general infinite dimensional normed space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments,  the question has a negative answer if $V$ is too big.

To be precise, suppose that $T$ is an injective compact linear operator from $V$ to $W$.   As it is well known, the
range of a compact operator is always a separable space and hence $T(V)$   is separable.  This in turn implies that the cardinality of
$T(V)$ is at most $2^{\aleph_0}$.  Consequently, if $V$ has a cardinality strictly bigger than $2^{\aleph_0}$, no compact
operator defined on $V$ is injective.

On the other hand,  this question is likely to be a lot  more  interesting if one assumes that $V$ and $W$ are separable spaces.   In that
case the relationship between $V$ and $W$ is bound to play a much bigger role. Observe that my reasoning above
completely ignores $W$.